# how to display in react render without rerendering, automatically changing values of mobx store instance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

how to pull in real time properties of an mobx class?

i made an instances of mobx store in which i calculate the years and days 
of several planets.
each planet is an instance which uses PlanetStore function
with a setInreval which allways add days and years.
i made a list with all the instances.

now, i want to dispaly this changes of years and days in real-time in a react-mobx componenet. but, its not observable. how can i do this??

```
@observer
class Calendar extends Component{

    render(){
        let planets = planetStore.Planets *just getting names of planets not relevant
        let planetArr=[]
        for(let i=1; i<planets.length; i++){
            let key= Object.keys(planets[i])
            planetArr.push(key)
        }
        this.planets=planetArr
        planets.forEach(e=> calanderStore.loadPlanets(e))
        console.log(planetArr)
       console.log(calanderStore.list)
       calanderStore.showPercent()       
        return (
        <div id='calendar'> {this.planets.map((planet, index) => <Cal planet={planet} key={index}/> )} </div> )       
    }

}

export default Calendar
```

*making a instance for each planet

```
class CalendarItem{
  @observable currentPrecent=0
  @observable planetName

  constructor(planetName,currentPrecent) {
        this.planetName=planetName
        this.currentPrecent=currentPrecent
        this.dayCounter=0
        this.yearCounter=-1
      }

      @action makeInstnace=(planet)=>{
        this.planetName=planet
        let currentPrecent=this.currentPrecent
        let dayCounter=this.dayCounter
        let yearCounter=this.yearCounter
       let planetData=new 
  CalendarItem(`${planet}`,`${currentPrecent}`,`${yearCounter}`,`${dayCounter}`)

   return (
      planetData
   )
      }


    }   
export default new CalendarItem();
```

```
@observer
class Cal extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state={rerender:''}
        this.planetName=this.props.planet
        this.currentPrecent=0   
        this.dayCounter=0
        this.yearCounter=-1
    }

    render(){
        let planet=this.props.planet

      **here i take the planet from the list of instances i made in CalandareStore Below**
 dayCounter=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(calanderStore.list[planetIndex].dayCounter))
      console.log(dayCounter)
      let yearCounter=planet.yearCounter



        return(
            <div className="calendaritem">       **the instance is being updated
            <span>{dayCounter}</span>              but it is not observed in here
            <div></div>
            <div>{calanderStore.list[planetIndex].yearCounter}</div>
```

```
class CalanderStore {
@observable list=[] *list of instances*

@action loadPlanets=(planetName)=>{
            console.log(planetName)
            planetName=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(planetName))
            planetName=Object.keys(planetName)
            console.log(planetName)
            let ifexist=this.findPlanetFromList(planetName)    
            if(ifexist.length==0){        
          let newPlanet=CalendarItem.makeInstnace(planetName)

           return this.list.push(newPlanet)
            }
              }

 @action  showPercent= (id)=> {
          console.log("Calander test now")   
          this.list.forEach(id=>{
                id=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(id)) 
                let index=planetStore.findPlanetIndex(id.planetName)
          let  test=planetStore.Planets[index][id.planetName].animationDuration['animation-duration']

               test=test.replace('s','0')
               test=parseInt(test)
               console.log(test)
            let setTimer=(id)=>{
              // id=id[0]
              // planetName=id[0].planeName

              // id=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(id))

              if (id.currentPrecent < 100) {
                console.log(id)
                id.currentPrecent += 1;  
                id.dayCounter=Math.round(id.currentPrecent*planetStore.Planets[index][id.planetName].daysInyear/100)      
              }
              else {
                id.currentPrecent=0
                id.dayCounter=0;
                id.yearCounter+=1;
                console.log(id.dayCounter)
              }
            }
            // let getanimationduration=this.getAnimeDuration
            // let totalDuration = getanimationduration(planetName)
              setInterval(() => {
              setTimer(id)}, test);

          })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can control whether the component should update or not there is a function of react component class

```
shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState, nextContext ) {
    /* compare nextState with your current states properties if you want to update on any basis return true if you want to render the component again  */
    return true; // will re-render component , 
    return false; // do not re-render component even if you change component states properites
}
```

Comment: nextProps contains that prop the new props , and nextState contain new State properties

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am using MOBX , this methods doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is going on with your code, but I have noticed that you are using `setInterval` inside the `@action`.

Mobx actions only apply to the current stack, code inside the `setTimeout`, `Promise`, `setInterval` does not run in the same stack.
Mobx has special functions for writing asynchronous code.

[Writing asynchronous actions](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html)

Comment: thanks, fixed it by setting the SetInterval in the rendreing componenet ,to call the action- setimer